# Buscar los paises de un continente con una api y fetch

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Hola estoy haciendo un ejercicio de javascript y me estoy volviendo loca porque sigo los pasos que me han dicho y no me sale. Estoy tratando de sacar de una api https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all los paises que pertenezcan al continente que se introduzca en un input del html. Los nombres de id estan bien puestos, es un error en el código. Este es mi codigo (el ultimo que he intentado porque llevo dos dias probando):

```
'use strict'


console.log('Cargada app')

let url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'

let aPaises = []

let inCont = document.querySelector('#in-continente')

let outPaises = document.querySelector('#ul-paises')

let btnBuscar = document.querySelector('#btn-buscar')

let html 

btnBuscar.addEventListener('click', onClickPaises)

inCont.addEventListener('change', onClickPaises)

function onClickPaises() {

    fetch(url)

    .then(data => data.json())

    .then(data => {

        aPaises = data

        aPaises = aPaises.map(item => { 

            if (item.region == inCont.value) 

                return item.name

     } )   

     outPaises.innerHTML =  `

     <li>

         ${aPaises}

     </li>`

     console.log(aPaises) }

    )  
 }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongo un ejemplo obteniendo todos los países de la API (url original de la pregunta):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Get countries</title>

    <style type='text/css'>
        div {
            padding: 2.5%;
        }
        input,
        select {
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding      : 9px;
        }
        select {
            width: 100%
        }

        .content {
            margin: 5% auto;
            width : 80%;
        }
        .content div {
            border-radius: 9px;
            border       : 2px solid grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='content'>
        <select id='regions'>
            <option>Selecciona un continente:</option>
            <option value='Americas'>Americas</option>
            <option value='Asia'>Asia</option>
            <option value='Europe'>Europe</option>
            <option value='Oceania'>Oceania</option>
            <option value='Polar'>Polar</option>
        </select>


        <div id='results' style='margin-top: 32px'>
            <h3 id='selected-region'></h3>
            <ul id='founded-countries'></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // function declarations

        function loadCountries()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById('regions');
            var region = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

            var url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';
            fetch(url)
                .then(data => data.json())
                .then(data => {
                    var countries = data;

                    var regional_countries = [];
                    countries.forEach(item => {
                        if (item.region == region) {
                            regional_countries.push(item.name);
                        }
                    });

                    if (regional_countries.length > 0) {
                        setTheCountries(regional_countries, region);
                    }
                });
        }

        function setTheCountries(countries, region)
        {
            var result_title = 'Hay ' + countries.length
                + ' países en "' + region + '"';

            var html = '';
            countries.forEach(item => {
                html += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
            });

            document.getElementById('selected-region').innerHTML = result_title;
            document.getElementById('founded-countries').innerHTML = html;
        }


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // add event listeners

        document.querySelector('#regions')
            .addEventListener('change', loadCountries);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisando la [documentación](https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-region)  no es necesario que traigas todos las ciudades en la primera consulta ya existe un método para retornar los países según el continente (región) revisa https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-region

Aqui un ejemplo de como implementarlo.

```js
function getPaises(elSelect){

  console.log(elSelect.value)
  let url = 'http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/'
  fetch(url+elSelect.value)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    myJson.forEach(item => {
       var paisOption = document.createElement("option");
       paisOption.className = 'pais_option'
       paisOption.value = item.name
       paisOption.text = item.name
       pais.prepend(paisOption)
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getPaises(this)">
  <option value="">Selecciona Region</option>
  <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
  <option value="Americas">Americas</option>
  <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
</select>
<select id="pais">
  <option value="">Selecciona Pais</option>
</select>
```